# SED how to replace Line with Regex

Tags: linux, bash, vim, sed

quick question

I have this line:

```
regexp: \[apm,(.*)\]apm-(.*)\.pivotal
```

And I want to be like that:

```
regexp: \[apm,(.*)\]app-metrics(.*)\.pivotal
```

The sed command that I'm using and it's not working is that one:

```
sed -i -E 's/regexp: \\[apm,(.\*)\\\]apm-(.\*)\\.pivotal/regexp: \\[apm,(.\*)\\\]app-metrics(.\*)\\.pivotal/g' FILE_THAT_CONTAINS_THE_LINE
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and explain what "it's not working" means in this case. Show the wrong output or the error message.

Comment: It's not a "doubt", it's a "question". A "doubt" means you don't believe something. That's a fairly common misunderstanding in a couple of countries where people learn English as a second language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i -E 's/regexp: \\\[apm,\(\.\*\)\\\]apm-\(.\*\)\\\.pivotal/regexp: \\[apm,(.*)\\]app-metrics(.*)\\.pivotal/' file.txt
```

you have some escapes missing

Answer (score 2):

Try to simplify it

```
sed '/regexp:.*apm.*apm-.*pivotal/s/apm-/&metrics/' FILE...
```

Comment: I did something a little bit different, exchanging the delimiter `sed -r 's|\]apm|&-metrics-|g' file`